# FreeBSD/FreeNAS: How to change group for multiple users?

Tags: freebsd, shell, truenas, groups

I need to change group membership for a bunch of users.

How do I

1. list all users?
2. change multiple users to `nogroup` primary group?
3. add secondary/auxiliary groups to multiple users?

Basically I need to change all the users that are currently in the `clients` group to `nogroup` and add `clients` as an auxiliary group to them.

Can this be done via shell without individually editing each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. list all users?

```
pw usershow -a
```

> 2. change multiple users to nogroup primary group?

There's a hundred different ways to do this... I would:

```
foreach u ("list" "of" "users")
    pw usermod -n $u -g NewPrimaryGroup
end
```

You could even get the list of users from a subcommand, like `pw groupshow OldGroupName | sed -e "s/.*://" -e "s/,/\ /"`

> 3. add secondary/auxiliary groups to multiple users?

Again, a few ways to do this...

If you know the full list of secondary groups that the users should be in:

```
pw usermod -n UserName -G "Secondary Group List"
```

If you don't know the full list, or just want to add users to a group:

```
pw groupmod -n SecondaryGroup -m NewUserName
```

And removing is similairly

```
pw groupmod -n SecondaryGroup -d OldUserName
```

> Basically I need to change all the users that are currently in the clients group to nogroup and add clients as an auxiliary group to them.

```
foreach u (`pw groupshow clients | sed -e "s/.*://" -e "s/,/\ /"`)
    pw usermod $u -g nogroup
    pw groupmod clients -m $u
end
```

(The above snippet is untested, but looks good after 3 seconds of double-checking, also written for `csh` as that's FreeBSD's default shell for users)